# Store graph trained in python, use in Android application

Tags: android, python, c++, tensorflow

I'd like to be able to train a neural network using the Python API on a computer, and then use the resulting graph later in an Android application (using the C API). Unfortunately, any examples I could find of this workflow refer to parts of the API which have been removed (such as `freeze_graph`). When attempting to do this myself, I get a number of errors pertaining to uninitialized variables or kernel ops that aren't available.

What is the intended workflow for this process? Note that the answer doesn't necessarily need to be Android-specific, as long as it covers saving a graph and using it later in C/C++.

Comment: As long as you can serialize your graph from the Python code to file, you can read it later in C++. What do you know about the data you are saving?

Comment: I don't have any problem saving the graph, but when I load it in C I get errors like `No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Mod' with these attrs` or messages about missing names.

Comment: Are your PC and Android TensorFlow versions both up-to-date (or at least the _same_)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 0.9.0 everywhere. For the record, I'm having the same issues using the C API on OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After significant trial and error, I found that the `freeze_graph` script is absolutely vital for this to work. You can find it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py). My current workflow is:

1. Generate the graph and train the network (in Python).
2. Save the graph definition and checkpoint. AFAIK the graph *has* to be saved in text format.
3. Use Bazel to build the `freeze_graph` executable.
4. Run the `freeze_graph` executable with the desired parameters for graph definition location, checkpoint location, and desired output node name.
5. In C, create a session, load the graph file, and run the session with the desired input tensors. If you freeze the graph, initializing variables is *not* required.